# How many of these are topologies?

Tags: general-topology

> Let $X$ be a set with $3$ elements. The set of subsets of the power
>   set of $X$ is $2^{2^3}$ elements. How many of these are topologies?

Is there a trick to this problem, or is it just a "plug and chug" casework thing?

Comment: Maybe it might help to look at finite topologies [as preorders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_topological_space#Specialization_preorder).

Comment: Another fact which might come handy is that every point has the smallest neighborhood. (Spaces with this property are called [finitely generated spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finitely_generated_space) or Alexandrov spaces.

Comment: In http://at.yorku.ca/cgi-bin/bbqa?forum=homework_help_2000&task=show_msg&msg=0041.0001 I give them all.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**: a topology on a finite set is determined by its minimal basis (which amounts to choosing a minimal open set containing each point).

Answer (score 2):

I think it's really just systematic listing, and trial and error.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_topological_space#3_points

Answer (score 2):

Let the elements be $a$, $b$, and $c$. We find the number of topologies.

**Case 1.**

$\mathcal{T}$ has no singleton sets.

1. It could have no doubleton sets. Thus it is the trivial topology, so there is $1$ way to pick this.
2. It could have $1$ doubleton. There are $3$ ways to pick this.
3. It could have more than $1$. But then their intersection would be a singleton, which is impossible.

**Case 2.**

$\mathcal{T}$ has $1$ singleton set.

1. It could have no doubleton. There are $3$ ways to pick the singleton.
2. It could have $1$ doubleton. All of these work, so there are $3 \times 3 = 9$ ways $(3$ ways to pick single, $3$ double$)$.
3. It could have $2$ doubletons. Then their intersection must be the singleton $($since $X$ has $3$ elements, the intersection of any $2$ element set is a $1$-element one$)$. Thus once we fix the singleton, we have to select the doubletons containing it. So there are $3$ ways to select.
4. It could have all $3$ doubletons. But then it would have more than $1$ singleton, impossible.

**Case 3.**

$\mathcal{T}$ has $2$ singleton sets. Thus it must contain their union, a doubleton.

1. It could have $1$ doubleton. This works, so there are $3$ ways.
2. It could have $2$ doubletons. This also works. There are $3$ ways to pick singles, $2$ to pick extra double. So there are $3 \times 2 = 6$ ways.
3. It could have $3$ doubletons. But this is impossible, since it would have all $3$ singletons.

**Case 4.**

$\mathcal{T}$ has $3$ singletons. This is the discrete topology, so there is $1$ way.

---

So the total is $$1 + 3 + 3 + 9 + 3 + 3 + 6 + 1 = 29 \text{ topologies}.$$